# Facebook social plugins (like/send) are getting wrong Canonical url's from our site

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, canonical-link

This is a weird problem, never faced before & hope I'll never face it again. Our website worldocricket.com is running on wordpress. Its related to news website so we are using social plugins like facebook's like & twitter's tweet buttons etc..

We created some new pages on our site, they are outside of the wordpress folder but on the same domain & are are connected with wordpress using [wp-load.php]. They all are working fine but when we tried to create facebook like button for one of our new pages; using fb developers tool (like button creator)  **www.developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/** , it spoiled our lunch.

On adding page url " **wwww.worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php** " in *'URL to Like'* box, it showed like counts in preview, on clicking 'like' & 'send' buttons, it revealed that it is liking/sending the main url of the site ( **www.worldocricket.com** ) which we don't want to, the url we added (or we want to be shared) was different. I thought that was a temporary problem but even after 24-36 hrs we got the same results.

We added og:title / og:type / og:url / og:image in the header after googling.

```
<meta property=”og:title” content=”ACC Asia Cup 2012”/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php" />
<meta property=”og:site_name” content=”World Of Cricket”/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/temptaby/images/asiacup12logo.jpg"/>
```

But it also proved to be useless. We then used fb debugger ( **www.developers.facebook.com/tools/debug** ), it showed that it is fetching right url but there is wrong Canonical URL. So we used `<link rel="canonical" href="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php">` but the result was same. :/

---

Our website : http://worldocricket.com

We want like button on http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php

***Question is : How to get facebook social plugins (like , share , send) working correctly on our site's respective page?***

Answer (score 0):

According to the debugger, when the crawler reaches `http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php` it's finding multiple og:url tags, I've verified this in curl:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="ACC Asia Cup 2012"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="World Of Cricket"/>
<meta property="og:url"   content="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/accasia312.php" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/temptaby/images/asiacup12logo.jpg"/>
<meta itemprop="name" content="ACC Asia Cup 2012">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Best Cricketing event in Asia organized by Asian Cricket Council (ACC).">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://worldocricket.com/categories/special/tournaments/asia-cup/2012/temptaby/images/asiacup12logo.jpg">
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="World Of Cricket"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1789905767"/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='World Of Cricket' />
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='189072694472072' />
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US' />
```

Make sure you're only returning one set of tags and they're valid

Comment: Thanks @lgy , plugin named 'Facebook Likes You!' was interfering, it was adding og:title & og:url same of the homepage and that is why I was getting wrong canonical URL.

I disabled it and now everything is working fine except the title, when I share it on fb (copy/paste link of Asia Cup page), it shows 'worldocricket.com' in the title which is wrong.

I'll try to remove extra tags & then will reply here.

Comment: The domain name of the URL is shown in the Like stories as far as I know - this is in addition to the og:title tag, usually on the next line

Comment: Again, another plugin was interfering, I disabled it too :/ I almost solved all the errors, you can see debugger isn't giving any error now although there is 1 duplicate "og:site_name", it is also because of a plugin. (I really hate wp-plugins now :p).

I want to know that if there is any unique code that I can add in the header of 'specific' page to stop the functionality of all plugins.

2nd, as I'm new to stackoverflow, should I delete this question or answer that plugins were interfering ! What you suggests as you are an experienced member of this (SOF) community.

Comment: I mostly only answer Facebook questions so i'm not 100% sure, but if you don't think my answer was correct you could add your own - i've seen people add their own solution and then accept it (so people who find the question in future can see what the answer was)